# Proper use of SVG

Tags: svg

```css
.change_on_hover:hover {
fill: blue;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg class="change_on_hover" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <g transform="translate(2.000000, 7.000000)"  stroke-width="3.2">
            <path d="M82.4167002,49.9034716 C84.8675809,48.3199417 88.5439018,45.7813059 93.4456631,42.0915546 C94.8563844,40.8929994 96,41.2925475 96,42.9875943 L96,81.7585389 C96,83.4648814 94.8652521,83.8649595 93.4456631,82.6640123 C88.3728682,78.5275499 84.5682721,75.7074861 82.0318746,73.961864" id="Layer-1"></path>
            <rect id="Layer-2" x="0" y="40" width="82" height="45" rx="5"></rect>
            <circle id="Layer-3" cx="60" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
            <circle id="Layer-4" cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
<svg  class="change_on_hover" width="100px" height="100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M81.23,17H18.77c-3.71,0-6.68,2.43-6.77,5.58V68.32C12,71.45,15,74,18.77,74H48V85H30.5a1.5,1.5,0,0,0,0,3h39a1.5,1.5,0,0,0,0-3H51V74H81.23C85,74,88,71.45,88,68.32V22.68C88,19.55,85,17,81.23,17ZM85,68.32C85,69.77,83.27,71,81.23,71H18.77c-2,0-3.77-1.23-3.77-2.68V22.62C15,21.18,16.73,20,18.77,20H81.23c2,0,3.77,1.23,3.77,2.68Z"/><path d="M55.27,36.63a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-2,.65L45.19,53a1.5,1.5,0,1,0,2.67,1.37l8.06-15.75A1.5,1.5,0,0,0,55.27,36.63Z"/><path d="M64.86,36.08a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-2.12,2.12l7.48,7.47-7.48,7.47a1.5,1.5,0,1,0,2.12,2.12l8.54-8.53a1.5,1.5,0,0,0,0-2.12Z"/><path d="M38.4,36.08a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-2.12,0l-8.54,8.54a1.5,1.5,0,0,0,0,2.12l8.54,8.54a1.5,1.5,0,0,0,2.12-2.12l-7.48-7.47L38.4,38.2A1.5,1.5,0,0,0,38.4,36.08Z"/></svg>
```

Why some of the SVG does not change color on hover?

I am using image tags and then linked my SVG. I have converted the image to SVG using jquery. some of the SVG change color and some don't, and some show mix effects.

Comment: Because in this case you have `fill="none"` declared. You may remove the fill attribute and add this in css: `.change_on_hover{fill:none;}`

Comment: how to overwrite it on over?. If I remove the fill=" none", hover works but change the color of the icon to black, any way to hover.@enxaneta

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented: Because in this case you have `fill="none"` declared. You may remove the fill attribute and add this in css: `.change_on_hover{fill:none;}`

```css
.change_on_hover{fill:none;}
.change_on_hover:hover {
fill: blue;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg class="change_on_hover" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <g transform="translate(2.000000, 7.000000)"  stroke-width="3.2">
            <path d="M82.4167002,49.9034716 C84.8675809,48.3199417 88.5439018,45.7813059 93.4456631,42.0915546 C94.8563844,40.8929994 96,41.2925475 96,42.9875943 L96,81.7585389 C96,83.4648814 94.8652521,83.8649595 93.4456631,82.6640123 C88.3728682,78.5275499 84.5682721,75.7074861 82.0318746,73.961864" id="Layer-1"></path>
            <rect id="Layer-2" x="0" y="40" width="82" height="45" rx="5"></rect>
            <circle id="Layer-3" cx="60" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
            <circle id="Layer-4" cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The second example is different. What apparently looks as strokes are in fact paths filled with black.

Comment: bro but you can see the difference on hovering, one fills blue, others outlines blue....doesnot look good in a project.@enxaneta

Comment: You will need to take your icons from the same set of icons. The second one is different. What apparently looks like strokes are in fact paths filled with black.

Comment: so what's the solution to add hover effect similar in each? I have 12 of these items.@enxaneta

Comment: Anyway, I can modify these same icons? as a rectangle have a fill area and stroke area....

Comment: One solution would be using icons from the same set. You can take a look here: https://thenounproject.com/. I would need to see all the icons to tell you something

Comment: while downloading I cannot see whether it will hover or not...Thanks for a source, but these are similar category icons downloaded from a single source.